# <head> JS scripts are not executing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, ibm-mobilefirst

I'm using JQuery Mobile, and now I would like to navigate through pages with the minimum of loading amount of scripts everytime a page is being loaded, I mean that I would like to import only **ONCE** all the general scripts of all the pages (JQuery.js, jquery_mobile.js, main.js etc...) and

So I have an `index.html` with the following code :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">

        <title>Hybrid App</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="jqueryMobile/jquery.mobile-1.4.4.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="jqueryMobile/jquery.mobile.icons-1.4.4.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mmenu.css" />

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" />

        <script>window.$ = window.jQuery = WLJQ;</script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jqueryMobile/jquery.mobile-1.4.4.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mmenu.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/initOptions.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="sharedResources/customersObject.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/messages.js"></script>   
    </head>
    <body style="display: none;">

        <div data-role="page" id="page">

            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/pages/splash-view.css" />

            <div data-role="header" id="header" data-position="fixed"></div>

            <div data-role="content" id="pageContent">
                <div id="splash-wrapper">
                    <div class="splash-content">

                        <a href="pages/faqs-view.html" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-theme="b" id="loginAction">Login</a>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        <div data-role="footer" id="footer" data-position="fixed"></div>

        <nav id="menu">
            <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">

                <!-- list of items in the slide sidebar menu (called drawer menu in Andorid -->

            </ul>
        </nav>

        <script src="js/pages/splash-view.js"></script>

    </div>

</body>
```

so when clicking on the link I go to an external HTML file located in : **pages/faqs-view.html** with the following code :

```
<div data-role="page" id="page" data-url="pages/faqs-view.html">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/pages/faqs-view.css">

    <div data-role="header" id="header" data-position="fixed"></div>

    <div data-role="content" id="pageContent">
        <div id="faqs-wrapper">
            <div class="faqs-content">
                <div data-role="collapsible-set" data-corners="false" data-collapsed-icon="arrow-r" data-expanded-icon="arrow-d" id="faq-set">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div data-role="footer" id="footer" data-position="fixed"></div>

    <nav id="menu">
        <p class="employee-name">Welcome, Ali</p>

        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">

            <!-- list of items in the slide sidebar menu (called drawer menu in Andorid -->

        </ul>
    </nav>

<script src="js/pages/faqs-view.js"></script>
```

The problem is that when loading the **faqs-view.html** page, I can see that none of the scripts included in the `<head>` are being executed, I have tried to put them after the `<body>` tag, but it's the same, **BUT** the CSS files are being interpreted.

How can I achieve that ? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Worklight-based applications are Single Page Applications](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v620/03_02_Building_a_multi_page_application.pdf). This means you should never navigate away from the index.html. Doing so will cause the app to lose its context to the Worklight framework, thus it will begin to fail.

If you'd like to add multi-page navigation to the application, you can do so using the API provided by 3rd-party frameworks. Here you are using jQuery Mobile.

1. You've changed the loading order of scripts. You shouldn't.

   - [Use the Worklight Studio wizard in order to create an app template with jQuery Mobile](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v620/03_03_Working_with_UI_frameworks.pdf) (new project > new hybrid application (click on "configure javascript libraries" > select the library you would like to add))
   - Keep initOptions.js, main.js and messages.js where they are by default, at the bottom
   - [The index.html you get](http://pastebin.com/QAnjjwDg) is your template with jQuery Mobile
2. If you want to replace the bundled *jQuery*, you need to *[comment out](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v620/03_03_Working_with_UI_frameworks.pdf)* (slide #6) the following script tag: `<script>window.$ = window.jQuery = WLJQ;</script>`. Worklight is bundled with jQuery 1.9.x.
3. For a bare-bones example of multi-page navigation in a Worklight-based application, using jQuery Mobile, [take a look at this project](https://github.com/IdanAdar/Multipage-Navigation-Using-jQM).

As you navigate between pages, you only replace the contents of the `data-role="page"`. The scripts have already been loaded. You can load additional scripts per where required when loading a specific page.

Comment: Hi @Idan : Thank you for your answer, it enlightens many things. doing what your Github code says, keeps the same problem : example the `js/jquery.mmenu.min.js` is not being executed as it has been already loaded.

Comment: Is the only way is including all the JS files ?

Comment: "not executed"? If the code is there, it should be available no matter in which page you are at, and you need to debug why your code does not get executed; best for you to create a small test case project demonstrating ONLY the problem and share it.

Comment: My Bad, I just noticed that a developer has screwed up the `main.js` and I pulled his edits. Sorry. thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

They are executed in the order you put them on the page.

```
window.$ = window.jQuery = WLJQ;
```

Cannot be executed before jQuery is included.

**Edit:**
When you load a new page without the header it's clear that it won't be excecuted because it is not there. 
When you replace html in your page you should look at the "on" function for events.

Comment: You didn't get my point. The JS files are not being executed when I go to the `faqs-view.html` page.

Comment: @Andro-Begg But it is true that `window.$ = window.jQuery = WLJQ;` throws an error because you haven't loaded any other scripts

Comment: Do you open a new page without the scripts in the header or is a div replaced with this page?